# Google places AutoComplete widget is generating a new Session Key for each new character

Tags: google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

We are using Google Autocomplete Widget and for each character entry one new session is getting created instead of using the existing session.

For example: for input "London". 1 session is created for 1st input "L", for second entry "Lo" one call for already exisiting session is invoked and 1 or more calls with new sessions are invoked

[image: multiple calls for second entry "Lo"]

We tried timeout to delay the invocation of the next calls but if we are idle for sometime and type in again new session is created and calls are invoked along with the old session

Comment: Hello! We need you to show us some code for us to see what's causing the issue. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to increase your chances of getting help.